# windows phone 8 maximize mediaElement volume

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

i'm building an apps that will play a sound under a certain condition. Whenever the sound play, i want the sound volume to reach the max even though the volume of the phone is 1/30(my nokia lumia 920). May i know how to set the volume the max without any interference from the phone volume button up and volume button down? I tried to set the volume in the XAML and C#, but it doesn't really work.

Xaml:

```
<MediaElement Name="mySound" Source="/Sounds/haha.mp3" AutoPlay="True" Volume="1" />
```

C#

```
mySound.Volume = 1;
```

Comment: Volume = 1 is limit, if you need you can use soundeffect and its instance http://tutorial.programming4.us/windows_phone/windows-phone-8---using-sound-%28part-1%29---playing-sounds-with-mediaelement,-using-xna-libraries,-playing-sounds-with-xna,-adjusting-playback.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128524/how-to-adjust-the-volume-of-the-audio-file-on-windows-phone-8