# How to adjust the volume of the audio file on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to increase the volume of the audio file but do not know how on windows phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have following media element in your xaml page...

```
<MediaElement Name="videoMediaElement"
    Source="Media/video1.mp4" 
    MediaOpened="videoElement_MediaOpened" 
    MediaEnded="videoMediaElement_MediaEnded" 
    MediaFailed="videoMediaElement_MediaFailed"
    CurrentStateChanged="videoMediaElement_CurrentStateChanged"
    PosterSource="Media/Video1_Poster.png"
    AutoPlay="False" />
```

And you have a button for increasing the volume, define this in your xaml page.

```
<Button Name="btnVolumeUp" Click="btnVolumeUp_Click" Content="-" />
<Button Name="btnVolumeDown" Click="btnVolumeDown_Click" Content="+" />
```

In the code behind file

```
private void btnVolumeUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (videoMediaElement.IsMuted)
    {
        videoMediaElement.IsMuted = false;
    }

    if (videoMediaElement.Volume > 0)
    {
        videoMediaElement.Volume -= .1;
    }
}

private void btnVolumeDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (videoMediaElement.IsMuted)
    {
        videoMediaElement.IsMuted = false;
    }

    if (videoMediaElement.Volume < 1)
    {
        videoMediaElement.Volume += .1;
    }
}
```

**From the MSDN documentation :**

You need to use SMTC(System Media Transport Control) Controls for that. These are the controls that pop up when hardware media keys, such as the volume control on a pair of headphones or the media buttons on some keyboards, are pressed. Your app can register to use these controls and can even pass back media metadata, such as album art or song titles, to be displayed by them.